# Monotonicity of measures

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on $\Omega$. Then $\mu(A)\le \mu(B)$ for all $A\subset B\subset \Omega$.

*pf.* Let $A\subset B$, let $C=A^c\cap B$. Then $A\cap C=\emptyset$ and $A\cup C = B$. By additivity, we have $\mu(A\cup C)=\mu(A)+\mu(C)=\mu(B)$. Therefore $\mu(A)\le \mu(B)$ for $\mu(C)\ge 0$ by non-negativity.

Comment: Looks good to me. (It might be slightly clearer to write $B \setminus A$ rather than $A^c \cap B$.)

Comment: BTW there's a proof-verification tag; it doesn't really matter with cases like this (beyond being orderly ;)), but it helps avoiding closure votes in less clear cases.